# Count strings of size 21 over the letters $\{A, C, G, T \}$ where an $A$ is always followed by a $C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

The question asks how many strings can we get if it is selected from {A,C,G,T}, and there always has an A followed by a C

Here is my solution:

$$C(11,10)\cdot 3 + C(12,9)\cdot 3^3 + C(13,8)\cdot 3^5+\cdots+C(20,1)\cdot 3^{19}+ C(21,0)\cdot 3^{21}$$

Where in $C(n,k)\cdot 3^{n-k}$, $n$ is the numbers of overall if we consider A and C together, k is the number of A's in the string, and we have 3 choices (C,G,T) for other positions in the string.

Am I right?

Comment: Treat "AC" as a single unit, say "X".  Of course now that "X" takes up 2 places so we need to consider what strings of {X, G, T} we can have where X occurs 0  1, 2,  up to 10 times.  That appears to be what you are doing.

Comment: Your logic is good.  The answers show some simpler ways to compute the number, but the answer you have is correct.

Comment: The language is confusing - do you mean that *any* A must be followed by a $C$, or do you mean, as you've written, that there must be at least one $A$ followed by a $C$? You've answered the "any" version correctly.

Comment: The answer for "there must be at least one $A$ followed by a $C$" can be gotten via inclusion-exclusion, which yields: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-k}{k}4^{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The generating function approach is that you are seeking the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the expansion of:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(x^2+3x\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-3x-x^2}$$

For every $n$, you get that you want the coefficient of $x^{21-n}$ in $(x+3)^n$, which  is $\binom{n}{21-n}3^{2n-21}$. Since we need $0\leq 21-n\leq n$, you restrict yourself to terms $11\leq n\leq 21$ and we get your sum:

$$\sum_{n=11}^{21}\binom{n}{21-n}3^{2n-21}$$

From the power series, you can use partial fractions and get that the $n$th coefficient is the nearest integer to:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Which for $n=21$ gives $72171863277$ in my calculator.

This is also twice the coefficient of $\sqrt{13}$ in the expansion of $\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}$, which is:

$$\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom {n+1}{2k+1}13^k3^{n-2k}$$

This gives a basic checksum, since it means that modulo $13$, the value is congruent to $(n+1)\cdot 2^{3n}$. For $n=21$. So when $n=21$ this is $22\cdot 2^{63}\equiv 9\cdot 8\equiv 7\pmod{13}$, and this is true for our value.

You can also compute the lower right value of the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}^{21}$$

which Wolfram Alpha also gives as $72171863277.$ Computing this exponentiation can be done somewhat efficiently using the method of repeated square.

Comment: Just seeing this today, not sure how it went without an upvote.  I like that nearest integer trick!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you are right. The number of strings of size $n$ with $k$ copies of $A$ (followed by $G$) with $2k\leq n$, is $\binom{n-k}{k}3^{n-2k}$. Hence the total number of such strings of size $n$ is
$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}3^{n-2k}.$$
Note that for $n\geq 3$, $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with $a_1=3$ and $a_2=10$. The final result should be $a_{21}=72171863277$ (see [OEIS A006190](https://oeis.org/A006190)).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ such that $A$ is always followed by a $C$.

Now, let's make the following observation: to begin constructing a string of length $n \geq 3$, we can either begin with a C,G, or T, following by a string of length $n-1$, or we can begin with an "AC", followed by a string of length $n-2$.   In other words, we can conclude that
$$
f(n) = 3 \cdot f(n-1) + f(n-2)
$$
I think this observation makes for a more elegant approach.  In particular, we are now simply solving a [linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

In fact, if we define $f(0) = 1$ (since there is one "empty string" of length $0$), then the relation above applies for $n \geq 2$.